# Convert MD5 array to String java

Tags: java, md5

I know that there is a lot of similar topics, but still... can someone provide me a working example of method which generates MD5 String.
I'm currently using MessageDigest, and I'm doing the following to get a string

```
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(messageDigest.digest())
```

I guess there is some better way to do that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which BASE64Encoder class is this?

Comment: Sorry....  here it is import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

Comment: I would avoid using sun.* classes in general...  See http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html

Comment: Check comments on the accepted answer, there's a bug in the code shown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] arr = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arr);
```

note: md5 is not considered as good hash algorithm anymore, consider choosing SHAs

Comment: FYI: MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not a cipher. Therefore, it does not *encrypt* data. Rather, it *hashes* data.

Comment: You do not really need the overhead of creating a BigInteger in order to print a MD5 string. Printing out 16 bytes as hex is not that difficult. Also you might want to edit the source code, as Adam Paynter pointed out, MD5 is not encrypting, but hashing your data.

Comment: WARNING - THIS ALGORITHM HAS A BUG. It will drop the leading 0 of the MD5 hash. To demonstrate: use this algorithm to hash this (no quotes) "wwq123456", and do the same using an online tool like this: http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php and note the missing 0. The proper hash is "07e1c0d9533b5168e18a99f4540448af" but this algorithm gives "7e1c0d9533b5168e18a99f4540448af". Oops.

Comment: basic problem of above answer is it remove zero in the starting if comes so i dnt think its good for using!!!!

Comment: I started to maintain a site that had this implementation, and ran into the bug that @DavidParks is warning us about, and lost time and hair on it, because I needed that 0 at the start to compare, was using on password solution and wasnt able to authenticate certain passwords.

Comment: These comments are confusing now that the answer has been edited to a completely different implementation.

Comment: Consider NOT using SHA1, as it is broken too.

Answer (score 16):

I'd use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

- Base64 - `Base64.encodeBase64(digestBytes)`
- Hex-string - `Hex.encodeHex(digestBytes)`

Comment: DigestUtils is the best solution on this page.  : )

Comment: Although it's great to use library code rather than writing your own algorithm, it does come with the disadvantage that the whole library has to be included in the distribution which is a shame for the sake of just one method. Obviously, if many other classes and methods are being used too then this is ideal but this probably won't generally be the case.

Comment: Hex.encodeHex is much faster than the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

```
// Convert to hex string
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
    if ((0xff & messageDigest[i]) < 0x10) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & messageDigest[i]));
}
String md5 = sb.toString();
```

This assumes you actually want your MD5 printed as an hex string, not BASE64-encoded. That's the way it is normally represented.

Comment: Just a word of warning if people use this solution. It doesn't allow for leading zeroes which may throw off hash checks. So 0x0E will just be printed as E and 0x00 will be stripped down to a single 0. A basic work around is to test the length of each result and prepend a zero when the length is 1.

Comment: @MechIntel You are completely right. I just updated the answer. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen next solution:

```
    byte[] digest = md.digest(someDataByteArray);
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : digest) {
        hex.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
```

Comment: This method will get actually the same result as what you get using the `md5` program in the *nix terminal, and, clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

...
String input = "westerngun";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); // not thread-safe, create instance for each thread
byte[] result = digest.digest(input.getBytes()); // get MD5 hash array, could contain negative
String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result).toLowerCase(); // convert byte array to hex string
```

If you want a number:

```
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16); // parse hex number to integer. If overflowed, use Long.parseLong()
```