# java md5 hash showing garbage

Tags: java, encryption, md5

I write a simple function to convert string to md5 and i see weird letters in the output. I assume some character encoding is messed up. Can i some one point what i am doing wrong?

```
public class App 
{   
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "helloWorldhelloWorldhelloWolrd";
    getHash(str);

}

public static void getHash(String str){
    try {
        byte[]  three = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest   md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(three);
        String  str1 = new String(thedigest,"UTF-8");
        System.err.println(str1);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**OUTPUT:**
  This is what i see

```
                                n?)?????fC?7
```

Comment: FWIW, if you can use third-party libraries, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) can get you hex-encoded MD5 hash in the one-liner with `Hashing.md5().hashString(string, Charsets.UTF_8).toString()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the bytes to a Hex string rather than straight to a String:

```
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(three);
StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : theDigest) {
  String conversion = Integer.toString(b & 0xFF,16);
  while (conversion.length() < 2) {
    conversion = "0" + conversion;
  }
  buff.append(conversion);
}
String str1 = buff.toString();
System.err.println(str1);
```

Comment: This won't work, quite.  You have to worry about negative bytes, which means that you have to do `b & 0xFF`, and then you have to worry about padding, because some bytes will get encoded as one character without a leading zero.

Comment: This is what I use: `final BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()); String.format("%032x", bigInt);`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Negative bytes will be in two's complement format no?

Comment: With your change i see this 6e-6329-647f-7f-22-47-42-5210661143-3837

Comment: Thx. to Jason's comment as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't display the digest as a String, (because it's only rubbish) you need to translate the bytes somehow so you can display them in a human readable form. I would propose a Base64 encoder.

There is another thread discussing how to convert a MD5 into a String [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752981/convert-md5-array-to-string-java).